# cannot pull Git remote repository from Sourcetree

Tags: git, github, ssh, atlassian-sourcetree

I Generated ssh keys and configured my git and SourceTree. I could git pull and do other operations from Git-bash. 
Note: I have added the following in .bashrc to make it work.

```
eval `ssh-agent`
ssh-add
```

However, when I try to git pull in SourceTree, I get this.

> git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false fetch origin
>   Permission denied (publickey,password). fatal: Could not read from
>   remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

When I tried to create ssh-key from Putty(windows), it goes further, but waits with this following message!

> git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false fetch origin
>   The server's host key is not cached in the registry. You have no
>   guarantee that the server is the computer you think it is. The
>   server's rsa2 key fingerprint is:
>
> ssh-rsa 2048 0f:ee:bb:1c:6c:b4:50:0e:54:d6:e9:55:9b:38:45:df If you
>   trust this host, enter "y" to add the key to PuTTY's cache and carry
>   on connecting. If you want to carry on connecting just once, without
>   adding the key to the cache, enter "n". If you do not trust this host,
>   press Return to abandon the connection.

if I open the terminal in SourceTree(which is git-bash), it asks me for passphrase. So, i suspect my .bashrc is not sourced by SourceTree. Or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 173):

I changed the client configuration from putty to **openssh**.

Go to: `Menu Tools` > `Options` > `SSH Client`

[image]

Comment: Worked on SourceTree v1.8.2.11.

Comment: Thank you. (win7 64bit, sourcetree v1.8.2.11, ssh)

Comment: Thanks :D win10 64bit, 1.8.3

Comment: This worked out for me. If  you have a working git cmd line already on your computer and a working private key for password-less operation, this is probably what you need to do.

Comment: Worked for me! I think I accepted some Mercurial download when I installed Sourcetree and this may have caused this issue but im not sure.

Comment: Definite solution

Comment: Thank you! I've been dealing with this for a few weeks...it would work in the terminal but not in Sourcetree. So I would use Sourcetree for adds and commits, but then I would go to the terminal to do push, pull, and fetch commands. It looks like I'll be able to do everything in the gui now.

Comment: Man I always miss these details when doing things from start!
This worked like a charm!

Comment: works to me too tks

Comment: Still the appropriate solution as of Sourcetree 3.4.15.

Answer (score 100):

I had the same problem and the solution for me was to call plink.exe manually with my server (GitLab):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Atlassian\SourceTree\tools\putty\plink.exe" gitlab.com
```

Press `y` when asked and you should be fine now!

Comment: It asked login/and password. What to do? I use rsa key.

Comment: @May12: no password is required at this stage. Just hit "y" to store the key in cache. Then return to SourceTree and you should no longer see the error.

Comment: Thanks!! it would be nice to know why source tree cant to this by itself!!! or popup a screen where it ask about!

Comment: Worked great, i have a specific port also which required setting with the -P option.

Comment: Worked for me too using `plink bitbucket.org` from my git bash in windows. Thank you!

Comment: In my case the server wants me to authenticate but does not accept the private key...

Comment: same for azure `plink.exe ssh.dev.azure.com` then typing "yes" then Ctrl+C there you go putty will trust the host and won't ask on the sourcetree GUI

Answer (score 16):

I was able to fix the problem by changing from "Putty/Plink" SSH to "OpenSSH" for the SSH provider.

```
Menu Tools > Options then SSHClient, select OpenSSH
```

Answer (score 5):

The best solution is to get a connection using Putty.

On the Host Name, put your gitlab project ssh address.
then, click 'Open' to connect.

That's it. SourceTree trust gitlab.com after all.
you may check the solution from the below link.
https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/31659457/windows-7-64bits-sourcetree-openssh-putty-git-pull-not-working

[image]

Comment: also worth noting you can simply start the putty ui, type in `github.com` or `bitbucket.org` or whatever your repo is into the hostname and you'll get the screenshot above

Answer (score 1):

gitlab.com currently (as of 06-28-2022) has a bug where it will fail using plink / ssh.

The fix is to set the "winadj" bug fix setting in your putty configuration for gitlab.com

Image below is of the screen "Chokes on winadj" is set to "On" instead of "Auto".  This fixes the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it's pretty complicated, but you can go to registry

`\HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-1530211238-4060388584-3209713061-1001\SOFTWARE\SimonTatham\PuTTY\SshHostKeys and add something like rsa2@2222:127.0.0.1 as REG_SZ and server fingerprint from error, like 0x10001,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`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue on my machine with newest Source Tree Version.
Only thing that helped to me is to open command prompt (not Power Shell) and execute following line of the code.

My Source Tree was installed under AppData not ProgramFiles - check path of your SourceTree app installation.

"C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\SourceTree\app-3.4.15\tools\putty\plink.exe" bitbucket.org

You will be prompted with following message

Store key in cache? (y/n, Return cancels connection, i for more info) y

enter y

Afterwards you will be prompted to enter (bitbucket or gitlab) credentials - you can ingore that.