# Getting error with self signed certificate in certificate chain for bower

Tags: node.js, npm, bower-install

We are getting below error in one of the machines. This is only happening with one user.
Upon building the code with gulp command, while dependencies are getting resolved, we are noticing below error.

> [15:26:18] [Compile:src] Installing bower package 'platform.js'
> (https://github.com/bestiejs/platform.js.git)... [15:26:29] [Core]
> Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain at
> TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1088:34) at TLSSocket.emit
> (events.js:198:13) at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:666:8)

This error is only observed while resolving bower dependencies.
Once this issue is observed, then we are not able to build any new games on that machine.

We have gone through handful of online solutions, but none seem to work.
Any solution is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have gone through following links but the issue persists.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437659/cannot-pull-git-remote-repository-from-sourcetree
https://medium.com/@jonatascastro12/understanding-self-signed-certificate-in-chain-issues-on-node-js-npm-git-and-other-applications-ad88547e7028
https://github.blog/2021-08-23-npm-registry-deprecating-tls-1-0-tls-1-1/
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/npm-install-fails-with-self-signed-cert-in-chain/1587286
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626990/receiving-error-error-ssl-error-self-signed-cert-in-chain-while-using-npm